# MVVM Light - change button content form Dynamic resource to binding

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

In my apllication in each view I have a "shared" user control that each view loads. this control contains just four buttons, but I need to change the content of each button depending by the view who loads it.
No problem until the content is just a string, but I don't know how to do once I need to put as a content of a button some controls, like a grid with images and text.

I tried creating a local resource with a key, but I need to set Content="{DynamicResource res}", so from ViewModel I cannot have any binding to the content...

```
<UserControl x:Class="PlusMatic.Presentation.Views.SubViews.FrontendButtonsView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="432" d:DesignWidth="211.2"
         DataContext="{Binding FrontendButtons, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" >

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="0,0,0,5">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Border x:Key="ButtonOneStructure">

                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding FlagPath}" Stretch="Uniform"  Margin="5"/>
                <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" Grid.Column="1" >
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{DynamicResource BigTextBlockPlusMatic}" >
                                        <TextBlock.Inlines>
                                            <Run Text="{DynamicResource 103ita}" />
                                            <LineBreak />
                                            <Run Text="{DynamicResource 103eng}" />
                                            <LineBreak />
                                            <Run Text="{DynamicResource 103fra}" />
                                            <LineBreak />
                                            <Run Text="{DynamicResource 103deu}" />
                                            <LineBreak />
                                            <Run Text="{DynamicResource 103esp}" />
                                        </TextBlock.Inlines>
                    </TextBlock>
                </Viewbox>
            </Grid>

        </Border>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.25*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.25*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.25*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.25*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button x:Name="ButtonOne" Margin="0,5,10,5" Content="{DynamicResource ButtonOneStructure}" Grid.Row="0" Style="{DynamicResource FrontendButtonStyle}" />
    <Button x:Name="ButtonTwo" Margin="0,5,10,5" Content="{Binding ButtonTwoContent}" Grid.Row="1" Style="{DynamicResource FrontendButtonStyle}" />
    <Button x:Name="ButtonThree" Margin="0,5,10,5" Content="{Binding ButtonThreeContent}" Grid.Row="2" Style="{DynamicResource FrontendButtonStyle}" />
    <Button x:Name="ButtonFour" Margin="0,5,10,5" Content="{Binding ButtonFourContent}" Grid.Row="3" Style="{DynamicResource FrontendButtonStyle}" />
</Grid>
```

Any help appreciated!

L.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the suggestion, I've choosen to implement it having one data template and a trigger inside which helps me to switch between two different controlTemplate:

```
<UserControl x:Class="PlusMatic.Presentation.Views.FrontendButtonsView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="432" d:DesignWidth="211.2"
         DataContext="{Binding FrontendButtons, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" >

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="0,0,0,5">
    <Grid.Resources>

        <!--Template per i bottoni frontend-->
        <!--Bottone uno-->
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonOneLangChangeControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
            <Border>
                <Grid >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=FrontendButtons.ButtonOneFlagPath}" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="5" />
                    <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" Grid.Column="1">
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{DynamicResource BigTextBlockPlusMatic}">
                            <TextBlock.Inlines>
                                <Run Text="{DynamicResource 103ita}" />
                                <LineBreak />
                                <Run Text="{DynamicResource 103eng}" />
                                <LineBreak />
                                <Run Text="{DynamicResource 103fra}" />
                                <LineBreak />
                                <Run Text="{DynamicResource 103deu}" />
                                <LineBreak />
                                <Run Text="{DynamicResource 103esp}" />
                            </TextBlock.Inlines>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Viewbox>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonOnePictureAndTextControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
            <Border>
                <Grid >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=FrontendButtons.ButtonOnePicturePath}" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="5" />
                    <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" Grid.Column="1">
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{DynamicResource BigTextBlockPlusMatic}">
                            <TextBlock.Inlines>
                                <Run Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=FrontendButtons.ButtonOneTextToShow}" />
                            </TextBlock.Inlines>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Viewbox>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="ButtonOneDataTemplate">
            <Control x:Name="theControl" Template="{DynamicResource ButtonOneLangChangeControlTemplate}" />
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=UseButtonOneLangChangeControlTemplate}" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="theControl" Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource ButtonOneLangChangeControlTemplate}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=UseButtonOneLangChangeControlTemplate}" Value="false">
                    <Setter TargetName="theControl" Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource ButtonOnePictureAndTextControlTemplate}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>

    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.25*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.25*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.25*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.25*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button x:Name="ButtonOne" Margin="0,5,10,5" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ButtonOneDataTemplate}" Grid.Row="0" Style="{DynamicResource FrontendButtonStyle}" />
</Grid>
```

By simply binding the boolean property "UseButtonOneLangChangeControlTemplate" in the dataTrigger from ViewModel I can change runtime the data template.

L

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you'll need to use DataTemplates for each different view, then use a DataTrigger, or relevant trigger to switch between templates.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. This seems correct, but how can I do this from ViewModel? I got a message registered and I know when the view changes (because this is a UserControl included in many views), but the problem is how to change the content by using a binding to a property... Could you post an example?